# Return different objects based on conditional argument

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I need help with some code desiging. I have a package which is used in many projects.

```
$p = new Package();
$result = $p->method();
```

While the `Package` looks like:

```
class Package {
    public function method($fooArg = 1, $barArg = 1)
    {
        // some logic

        return new SomeClass(
            $fizzArg,
            $buzzArg
        );
    }
}
```

Now, in one project which is using `Package` I need to change returned class. So, the call will look like this:

```
$p = new Package();
$result = $p->method(10, 10, true);
```

And the `Package` will look like this:

```
class Package {
    public function method($fooArg = 1, $barArg = 1, $condArg = false)
    {
        // some logic

        if (false === $condArg) {
            return new SomeClass(
                $fizzArg,
                $buzzArg
            );
        }

        return new MyNewClass(
            $fizzArg,
            $fooBarArg
        );
    }
}
```

Which design pattern should be used here? I do not want to return different object types based on condition, because it seems very ugly to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you explicitly set `$condArg` from the calling script and it is the only argument that control which instance to return, consider to create a second public method to return `MyNewClass`, and extract `some logic` into private method to share it between 2 public methods:

```
class Package {
    public function method($fooArg = 1, $barArg = 1)
    {
        list $fizzArg, $fooBarArg = $this->someLogic($fooArg, $barArg);

        return new SomeClass(
            $fizzArg,
            $buzzArg
        );    
    }

    public function newMethod($fooArg = 1, $barArg = 1)
    {
        list $fizzArg, $fooBarArg = $this->someLogic($fooArg, $barArg);

        return new MyNewClass(
            $fizzArg,
            $fooBarArg
        );
    }

    protected function someLogic($fooArg, $barArg)
    {
        // some logic

        return [
            $fizzArg,
            $fooBarArg
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be resolved with a combination of the Factory and Dependency Injection patterns:

The example below is a bit long winded, but it illustrates the basic principle.  By providing your `Package` class with a factory implemented by the specific project.  You don't need to change the code of that class.  Instead, the changes are made with abstractions via interfaces.

```
/*
 * Shared library
 */

interface IEntity
{

}

interface IFactory
{
    /**
     * @param $arg1
     * @param $arg2
     * @return IEntity
     */
    public function create($arg1, $arg2);
}

class Package
{
    protected $factory;

    public function __construct(IFactory $factory)
    {
        $this->factory = $factory;
    }

    public function method($arg1, $arg2)
    {
        return new $this->factory->create($arg1, $arg2);
    }
}

/*
 * Project A
 */

class FactoryA implements IFactory
{
    public function create($arg1, $arg2)
    {
        return new EntityA();
    }
}

class EntityA implements IEntity
{
    public function construct($arg1, $arg2)
    {

    }
}

/*
 * Project B
 */

class FactoryB implements IFactory
{
    public function create($arg1, $arg2)
    {
        return new EntityB();
    }
}

class EntityB implements IEntity
{
    public function construct($arg1, $arg2)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But there is one condition I did not mention earlier. The case is that I do not have access to all projects using `Package`. Creating it and calling its methods in another projects cannot be changed. I can customize creating `Package` only in my one project and I can change sources of `Package`, but with restriction that it will not affect other projects/applications.

Answer (score 2):

From a purely theoretical point of view, the very idea to use such a package that has to return something else based on where it is used is very ugly. This way it means that the widely-used package depends on a details of the package that uses it and this to me is a signal that you have to scrap the idea entirely and not use this package in this one project.

Answer (score 0):

Your Package seems like a [Factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), it builds objects according to parameters. If I get it right, now you want to have different Packages for different projects with different objects.

Well [Abstract factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) is what you are looking for.

Make your Package abstract. Have two implementations, and load the proper package in the initiation phase you can use reflection or configuration or whatever PHP lets you do.

Note: It seems that there is some other logic in your Package class, if that logic is independent of building objects extract it to a different class, or vise versa.

Answer (score 0):

since you don't have access to all project using **Package**, and you can change the source of **Package** if it does not affect other projects, then it is safer to create a descendant of **Package** instead. this way, you can change existing methods without affecting other projects, and you can also add new methods.

```
include('package.php');

class myPackage extends Package(){
  public function newMethod($arg1, $arg2){
    return new otherClass($arg1, $arg2);
  }

  //if you want to change existing method
  public function method($fooArg = 1, $barArg = 1){
    //some new logic
  }
}
```

then you can use it in your project:

```
$obj = new myPackage();
if ($i_want_regular_class){
  $newObj = $obj->method(1, 2); // call parent's method or modified parent's method
} else {
  $newObj = $obj->newMethod(3, 4); // call new method
}
```

as for why i suggest you to create new method is because you already know which object you want to create, hence the argument passed to the method. so instead of putting the conditional in the method, why not put the conditional in the logic and call the appropriate method?